# Xserver や Conoha WING で flask などを用いたPythonファイルなどを追記したら500エラーや404がエラーが表示される

Tags: python, flask

**エラーログ**

```
AH01215: suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details: 

End of script output before headers: index.py
```

#### 試したこと

まず、自分のコードに誤りがあるかを確かめて見たのですが、ローカル環境では一応表示はされてpythonの機能も動いていました。

次に、.htaccessやhttpd.confの権限あたりについて色々調べたり、パーミッションを.htacceessには604,その他には基本的に755を付与してみました。.htaccessに以下のコードを記述すると直るかもと書いてあってので記述してみたのですが、こちらもうまくいきませんでした。

```
DirectoryIndex index.py index.html
Options Indexes
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .cgi .py .php
```

初めはConoha WINGで公開していて、もしかしたらConoha WINGとの接続みたいなものが設定か仕様でうまく動いていないのかもと思い、Xserverに変えてみたのですがやはりこちらでも同じような500番エラーが出ました。

エラーログの「End of script output before headers:」に関して調べて、htmlファイルにhttpのためのheaderを追記してみたのですが、これもうまくいきませんでした。

記述内容：

```
#! /opt/alt/python36/bin/python3.6
http/1.1 200 ok
Content-Type: text/html
```

#### 考えられること

flaskやpythonを公開するときは何か別に記述を施さないといけないのか。
記述の仕方が間違えているのか。

サイトで調べて出てくることは一通り行なってみたと思うのですが、どうしてもうまく公開ができません。何かもし心当たりがある方がいれば、どんな些細なことでも構いませんので、返答してくれたら嬉しいです。また、単純にまだサーバー関連のことで勉強不足であれば、参考になるサイトリンクなど掲載してくれたら助かります。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーログを取得して読んでみましょう。そしたら自分で解決できるかもしれませんし、できなかったら（この質問の本文を編集する形で）追記してみると、だれかアドバイスくれるかもしれません。今の質問文だと情報不足っス。

Comment: `AH01215` って SELinux が原因だったり CGI ファイルの改行コード違いが原因だったりでトラブルシューティングが超絶めんどくさい奴だ・・・この手の障害調査はリアルタイム性の低い掲示板向きではないので、詳しい人に直接触ってもらうほうが絶対手早いです。 // それでも stackoverflow で続けるならまだ情報不足です。とりあえずエラーログでも指摘されている suexec log を探して追記してください。あるいは suexec を一時的に無効にしてみるとかもアリでしょうね。